# looping through react array while mapping data problem

Tags: reactjs

i have array in which i want to  map and display objects value like name and desc in left-section and video_url on right section and below image section along it.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "DEFINE",
    desc: "Logicaldefine",
    video_url: "/assets/video/video.mp4",
    image: "/assets/images/AI.png",
  }]
```

**code**

```
{data.map((item, index) => {
            <div key={item.id}>
          <div className="left-section">
            <h2>{item.name}</h2>
            <p>{item.desc}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="right-section">
            <video width="500" height="300" autoplay muted>
              <source src={item.video_url} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            </div>;
            <div className="below-section">
            <img src={item.image} alt=""/>
            </div>
          </div>;
})}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: if there is no error then you should always `return` statement to show data

Answer (score 0):

The return statement is missing.

```
{data.map((item, index) => {
            return(<div key={item.id}>
          <div className="left-section">
            <h2>{item.name}</h2>
            <p>{item.desc}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="right-section">
            <video width="500" height="300" autoplay muted>
              <source src={item.video_url} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            </div>;
            <div className="below-section">
            <img src={item.image} alt=""/>
            </div>
          </div>);
})}
```